# Initialising an array with a single value in solidity

Tags: solidity, gas, arrays, memory

I want to create an array of all 1's. As per my understanding, doing it manually after declaration through a for loop will lead to high gas expense. So, is there any way to initialize an array at once, as we do in other programming languages like C

```
 int array[n]={1}
```

Here's what I'm doing right now, inside some solidity function:

```
        uint[] memory _amounts = new uint[](_supply);
        for(uint i=0;i<_supply;i++){
            _amounts[i]=1;
        }
```

Comment: I tested that code on remix and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an array at declaration like this:

```
  uint[3] memory c = [uint(1) , 2, 3];
```

The number of elements between the [] can't be more than the length of the array.
To read more you can look here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_arrays.htm

Comment: Can you do this with a dynamic memory array?